# Would a 9v battery be able to produce gas bubbles by water electrolysis at 1000 meters?

Tags: electric-current

I'm currently working on an underwater robot and was hoping to use the gas bubbles for buoyancy control .

Comment: If it works then I would collect the two gasses in different tanks, since otherwise any spark could make your robot explode.

Comment: Before you embark on designing any kind of active buoyancy control mechanism, it may pay off to investigate the minimal amount of energy needed. In this case it's given by pdV. Let's say you want to displace 0.1kg of seawater at 1000m, that's approx. W=1e7Pascal*1e-4m^3=1kJ, far more than what you can get out of a small 9V battery. You will certainly need something really beefy to power your robot, even if it's relatively small. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You will create the same amount of gas as at the surface but it will be under much more pressure at 1000m. This means it will displace less volume and therefore create less buoyancy. You will need to calculate the volume of the gas at the depth you want.

Edit: Rough estimate using ideal gas law, you would need 100X as much gas.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment of the situation. Yes we would be under 100ATM of static pressure. But that changes not only the gas equation, but also the solubility equation. At 100ATM I suspect (but do not have the numbers to support my claim) that it is possible that all the hydrogen and oxygen would directly dissolve, and no gas would be formed. Another way to consider this would be the amount of work required to create a molar gas bubble (displacing water), and compare with ~9eV * 6.0221413e+23 (1 Mole of 9eV).

Comment: Would the use of sea water facilitate the gas production process ???